# Failure to boot in Ubuntu for only-Ubuntu + Nvidia laptop

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

## Problem

I just received the Nvidia laptop I ordered specifically for coding and deep learning. So I just **erased Windows** while installing Ubuntu.

The installation procedures follow Ubuntu community listed below.

- [Create a bootable USB stick on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)
- [Installation Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)
- [Disk Space](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

I initially thought there would be no much pain since I do not need dual boot (as I said, I ordered this machine solely for coding and deep learning). However, I am get stuck in purple screen that looks like 
[image]

It seems that this issue is releated to Nvidia GPU driver, which governs the display. However, all the workarounds I could find assume users could access GRUB, which is **not** my case since I erased Windows.

Could some help me? Thank you in advance!

## Update

I would like to clarify several things

- I burned the USB correctly, and could see GRUB like the following, and finally could boot into USB by setting `nouveau.modeset=0`
  [image]
  [image]
- I completed all the steps in the Ubuntu installation and probably installed it correctly.
- After the Ubuntu installation, I tried to reboot the machine but initially it is all purple, and then the image shown before.

Comment: I do not know why some one downvote this question. It would be better if improvement for problem statement could be specified first.

Comment: You still have GRUB. It is required for Ubuntu-only booting, too.

Comment: @user535733 I see. But why I could not see that (something like the last image I showed)? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: GRUB sometimes hides on single-boot systems, since the boot choices are limited. Tap the left SHIFT key at the correct time to expose it.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you. I did as you said and referred to [Ubuntu community wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode). But nothing happened after I press the SHIFT when manufacturer logo appears.

Comment: @user535733 I am not sure if I wrongfully did something fatal to my machine

Comment: The manufacturer logo is the wrong time to expose GRUB. Try a second or two later

Comment: @user535733 Somehow I still could not see GRUB after several tries. But I bumped into an option in BIOS setting, which allowed users to switch between external GPU and integrated GPU. After choosing integrated GPU, voila, everything looks normal. However, I am not sure this is the ultimate solution.

Comment: Seems like a workaround. You still need to figure out how to expose GRUB. You can add your nouveau setting to grub without exposing it (see the proposed duplicate), then you can activate your GPU.

Answer (score -1):

An Ubuntu image is a "live" iso, so "burned" on a stick you can first check if it starts, without installing anything. So that's what I would do:

- Take the correctly "burned" usb stick and put it into an usb slot. Power up the machine and "tell" the bios from where to boot (..the usb stick)
- if you can't see the initial Ubuntu screen you may see an error message.Then your Iso hasn't been saved correctly
- if you can see that screen, start Ubuntu - but thats a sure sign that linux can cope with your graphics card.
  If installed Ubuntu usually uses the non proprietary nouveau driver. It might lag and looks grizzly. Now you would have to install the correct nvida driver for your card.

Maybe you did all these things, but didn't tell ;-). Then you probably installed an nvidia driver that is not working for your laptop

.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I **could** see initial GRUB when USB is plugged in, and I **could** see all the GUI when additionally setting `nouveau.modeset=0`, and the Ubuntu **could** be installed properly. The thing is when I reboot the system. The screen became what it is in the image I showed.

Comment: Thanks for downgrading. If you had mentioned the above, I've could have looked into another direction. But you probably know what that modeset=0 means. I'm off